# Multiple requests using EasyPHP

Tags: php, easyphp

Is there a chance to have multiple requests on different browsers and/or tabs using EasyPHP at the same time?
For example, right now I´m running a script that usually takes 4 to 6 hours, and in the meantime I would like to work on another website but it´s impossible, as the new site won´t work until the first script ends.

Answer (score -1):

Well I`m not sure what are you asking, but easyphp is just apache server so you can make as many virtual hosts as you wish... so that way you can make one script1/ and second script2/ 
So that way if you write to your browser script1/ you will be running first website... and you can on other tab write script2/ and run second website in same time...

you can look here: [Working on multiple sites with an easyPHP offline server](http://virtualdebris.co.uk/blog/05B63DE2) or just google apache virtual host....